# C++ - error: multiple types in one declaration

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am having some trouble with this program I am trying to make. When I compile it tells me I have an error: multiple types in one declaration inside this file on line 49.

```
#ifndef GRIDGAME_H
#define GRIDGAME_H

#include "GameType.h"

class GridGame {
public:
    GridGame();

    ~GridGame();

    enum GameType GetType() { return m_type; }

    void OutputGreeting() const;

    int NumPlayers() const;

    char GetPlayerSymbol(int player) const;

    int GetBoardSize() const;

    /* Returns NULL on good move, else returns err string.
     * Note that this check is game-neutral (at least for TTT and Reversi)
     */
    const char *IsLegalMove(int player, int row, int col) const;

    void OutputBoard() const;


protected:
    GridGame(enum GameType type, const char *name, const char *playerSymbols, int boardSize);

    void DoBasicMove(int player, int row, int col);

    // The only data member that the subclassed games should really
    // need full read/write access to, once game is set up.
    char **m_board;

private:
    enum GameType m_type;
    const char *m_gameName;
    int m_boardSize;
    const char *m_playerSymbols;

};

#endif //GRIDGAME_H
```

I don't see anything wrong, can anyone help me?

Edit: Line 49 is the last curly brace with the semi-colon.

Comment: Pretty sure `enum GameType GetType() { return m_type; }` should be `GameType GetType() { return m_type; }`

Comment: @shuttle87, It's still valid syntax, but not overly useful in C++.

Comment: @chris, good to know, I thought that wasn't valid in c++.

Comment: @shuttle87, It's just like `struct` AFAIK, where using it accesses the tag name. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44d1ce8c03ee6816

Comment: @unmerciful, This code [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/168fe0397921cffa). Perhaps your other header is the problem (missing a semicolon perhaps?)

Comment: @Chris, ok that makes sense. As for the OP, I would check that gametype.h doesn't have an error like a missing semicolon at the end of a class/struct definition that's spilling over into this file.

Comment: Could you reduce this to a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/) to save a lot of guesswork?

Comment: The problem is that `GameType.h` contains a definition that doesn't end in a semicolon

Answer (score 2):

The likely case is the `enum GameType` was not declared properly, namely, that your `enum` is probably declared as such:

```
enum GameType
{
    First,
    Second,
    //...
    Last
}
```

The issue being that `enum`s and any type declaration need a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of its declaration, like so:

```
enum GameType
{
    First,
    Second,
    //...
    Last
};
```

Comment: "do not need" should be an indicator that it doesn't solve a compiler error.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the 'enum' keyword but it still gives me that error.